# Iteration in python

Tags: python, loops

I am not getting the expected result from this code below, as I expect a display of numbers excluding 4.

```
z = 0

while z < 6:
    if z == 4:
        continue
    z = z + 1
    print(z)
```

I get numbers from 1 to 4

Comment: You are testing is z == 4, if not, it adds 1, then prints. What would happen if z == 3?

Comment: For z == 3, the if statements fails. So, it goes on by performing `z = z + 1`. This makes `z = 4`. Then it prints `4`.

Comment: Wow! You've created an ```infinite loop``` in this case.  Because once it's in ```n==4``` if won't exit the while loop....  Try to run it in this great visual platform - https://pythontutor.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the heart of the post has to do with what does `continue` do?

From [tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loop_control.htm#:%7E:text=The%20continue%20statement%20in%20Python,both%20while%20and%20for%20loops.)

> The continue statement in Python returns the control to the beginning of the while loop. The continue statement **rejects all the remaining statements in the current iteration of the loop and moves the control back to the top of the loop**.
> The continue statement can be used in both while and for loops.

So they'd suggest something like the below instead.

```
z = -1

while z < 6:
    z = z + 1
    if z == 4:
        continue
    print(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment `z` first before the `if` condition to avoid going into an infinite loop. This will solve your problem. Just a simple edit in your code:

```
z = 0

while z < 6:
    z += 1
    if z == 4:
        continue
    print(z)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
z = 0

while z < 6:
    z = z + 1
    if z == 4:
       continue
    print(z)
```

Comment: Please don't just post code, but add an explanation.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you edit your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score -2):

The problem is your condition

```
if z == 4:
    continue
```

when z is equals to 4 your loop continues without incrementing the value of z to 5 so on so forth.

Below code should get you desired output

```
z = 0
while z < 6:
    if z != 4:
        print(z)
    z += 1
```